# Populating NumberPicker in custom made Dialog

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to populate a NumberPicker on a custom made dialog. At the moment I'm using a method which uses a View and inflates another layout (the dialog), the method should then populate the NumberPicker but when I call it in onCreate it doesn't.

The code for the method:

```
public void fillArray() {

    View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_activity, null);
    np_hours = ( NumberPicker ) inflatedView.findViewById( R.id.hourNumber );
    np_minutes = ( NumberPicker ) inflatedView.findViewById( R.id.minuteNumber );
    String[] hoursArray = new String[25];
    String[] minutesArray = new String[61];
    for( i = 0; i < hoursArray.length; i++ ) {
        hoursArray[i] = Integer.toString( i );
    }

    for( x = 0 ; x < minutesArray.length; x++ ){
        minutesArray[x] = Integer.toString( x );
    }
    np_hours.setMinValue( 0 );
    np_hours.setMaxValue( 24 );
    np_hours.setWrapSelectorWheel( false );
    np_hours.setDisplayedValues( hoursArray );

    np_minutes.setMinValue( 0 );
    np_minutes.setMaxValue( 60 );
    np_minutes.setWrapSelectorWheel( false );
    np_minutes.setDisplayedValues( minutesArray );
}
```

EDIT:

The idea of this is to pick the duration of something (not the time) - sorry if this caused confusion!

Comment: If you want a number picker to pick the time why not use a time picker? see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html

Comment: Because I want it to pick the duration of an activity i.e. hourNumber = 3 hours, minuteNumber = 2 minutes. Probably should have stated that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just want consecutive numbers there's no need to create the side arrays.

You can do it as follows:

```java
public void fillArray() {
    
    View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_activity, null);
    np_hours = ( NumberPicker ) inflatedView.findViewById( R.id.hourNumber );

    np_hours.setMaxValue(24);
    np_hours.setMinValue(0);
    
    np_minutes = ( NumberPicker ) inflatedView.findViewById( R.id.minuteNumber );
    np_minutes.setMaxValue(60);
    np_minutes.setMinValue(0);
    
}
```

If this is not working please post your XML layout and the full activity code (at least the onCreate() method).

Reference:

[NumberPicker Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setMaxValue%28int%29)

**Update**

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.plan_activity );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu ) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu );
    return true;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void adActivity( View view ) {    
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View parentView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_activity, null);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(parentView);
           builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.add_activity, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   //Stert
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    fillArray(parentView);
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    AlertDialog mainAlert = builder.create();
    mainAlert.show();
    
}

// Method to fill the NumberPicker's
public void fillArray(View view) {

    View inflatedView = view;
    np_hours = ( NumberPicker ) inflatedView.findViewById( R.id.hourNumber );
    np_hours.setMaxValue(24);
    np_hours.setMinValue(0);

    np_minutes = ( NumberPicker ) inflatedView.findViewById( R.id.minuteNumber );
    np_minutes.setMaxValue(60);
    np_minutes.setMinValue(0);


}
```

Comment: This didn't work :/. I've edited my code into the main post! :)

Comment: Am I wrong or you're not calling adActivity(View v); in the onCreate()?

Comment: How is fillArray() supposed to be called?

Comment: adActivity(View view); is called in the 'plan_activity.xml' file:
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/addActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/planActivities"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="adActivity"
        android:src="@drawable/add_activity" />

Comment: You're double inflating the same add_activity layout. Try to move fillArray() to the botton of the method and pass the parent view rather than inflating it in the method itself.

Comment: The updated version works!
Thanks a lot for your help :)